# Is this apparent Class Action settlement a spam message?

Tags: scams

I got the following email:

> CLASS ACTION SETTLEMENT NOTICE
>
> LEGAL NOTICE BY ORDER OF THE SUPERIOR COURT OF CALIFORNIA FOR THE
>   COUNTY OF SANTA CLARA
>
> Douglas v. DHI Group, Inc. et al.; Case No. 18-cv-331732
>
> You are receiving this Notice because you have been identified as a
>   Class Member who will be entitled to a settlement payment if a
>   settlement is finally approved unless you timely exclude yourself. To
>   file a Claim Form, click here.
>
> The parties estimate you will receive up to $500 if you file a claim.
>   However, the final amount you will receive depends on the number of
>   claims filed. Based on prior claims rates in other settlements, the
>   parties anticipate that payouts will be between $50-$200.
>
> This proposed settlement covers people about whom DHI Group, Inc. and
>   Dice Inc. (together, “Dice”) created an Open Web profile since July
>   26, 2012, and with whom a third party sought to communicate using
>   Dice’s software, as well as those people who requested a copy of their
>   Open Web profile from Dice.
>
> A state court authorized this Notice. This is not a solicitation from
>   a lawyer. Read this notice carefully, as it affects your rights.
>
> For more information, visit www.DiceFCRASettlement.com or call
>   1-855-598-4037.
>
> WHAT IS THIS CASE ABOUT? The individual who brought the lawsuit
>   (called the Plaintiff) claims that DHI Group, Inc. and Dice Inc.
>   (together, “Dice”) violated a statute applicable to consumer reporting
>   agencies called the Fair Credit Reporting Act (“FCRA”). Specifically,
>   he alleges that Dice was a “consumer reporting agency” preparing
>   “consumer reports” under the FCRA when it gathered information from
>   various online sources regarding job seekers and then compiled that
>   information into “candidate profiles” for sale to potential employers
>   and recruiters, and that Dice violated the FCRA in several other ways
>   by not treating the profiles as “consumer reports.”
>
> Dice denies that it is a “consumer reporting agency” under the FCRA
>   and that candidate profiles are “consumer reports.” Dice maintains
>   that it did not do anything wrong and that the FCRA does not apply to
>   Dice or its activities.
>
> WHO IS INCLUDED? If your name is located on the top of this Notice,
>   you are a Class Member and are part of the Settlement, unless you
>   timely exclude yourself from it.
>
> The precise definition of a Class Member can be found in the Long Form
>   Notice.
>
> WHAT DOES THE SETTLEMENT PROVIDE? The parties estimate you will
>   receive up to $500 if you file a claim. However, the final amount will
>   depend on the number of claims filed, and could be substantially less
>   than $500. Based on prior claims rates in other settlements, the
>   parties anticipate that payouts will be between $50-$200.
>
> This amount comes from a payment of $1 million by Dice to a fund from
>   which payments to Class Members, attorneys’ fees to Class Counsel, the
>   costs of the Settlement Administrator, and a service payment to the
>   Class Representative will be made. The final amount will depend on the
>   number of claims filed.
>
> Class Counsel will ask the Court to award them attorneys’ fees in an
>   amount no greater than one-third of the Settlement Amount ($333,333)
>   plus reasonable out-of-pocket expenses. The Court may award the
>   Plaintiff in this case a service award totaling up to $5,000 for the
>   time and effort he has put into this case on behalf of the Settlement
>   Class.
>
> You will only receive a benefit if you file a Claim Form online by
>   June 24, 2019, or if mailed, postmarked no later than June 24, 2019.
>   The Settlement also provides that Dice will implement certain business
>   practice changes. For more information, visit
>   www.DiceFCRASettlement.com.
>
> HOW DO I FILE A CLAIM? There are two ways to file a Claim Form: (1)
>   File online, at www.DiceFCRASettlement.com; or (2) Print a Claim Form,
>   available at www.DiceFCRASettlement.com, fill it out, and mail it
>   (with postage) to the address listed on the Claim Form. Printed Claim
>   Forms that do not contain a valid Notice ID (shown at the top of this
>   email) will not be processed. Claim Forms must be filed online or
>   postmarked by June 24, 2019.
>
> YOUR OTHER OPTIONS. If you don’t want to receive a cash payment or
>   other settlement benefits and don’t want to be bound by the Settlement
>   and any judgment in this case, you must send a written request to
>   exclude yourself. You must either send your exclusion by mail or
>   submit a letter via the Settlement Website at
>   www.DiceFCRASettlement.com, saying that you want to be excluded.
>   Exclusions must be submitted or postmarked no later than May 27, 2019.
>   If you exclude yourself, you will not receive benefits from the
>   Settlement. If you don’t exclude yourself, you will give up the right
>   to sue Dice about any of the issues related to this case. Please see
>   the Long Form Notice for additional details.
>
> If you don’t exclude yourself, you may object to the Settlement or to
>   the request for fees and costs by Class Counsel.
>
> The Long Form Notice, available at www.DiceFCRASettlement.com, further
>   explains how to exclude yourself or object.
>
> The Court will hold a hearing in this case on August 2, 2019 at 9:00
>   a.m., to consider whether to approve: (1) the Settlement; (2)
>   attorneys’ fees and costs for Class Counsel; and (3) a service award
>   of $5,000 for the Class Representative in this case. You may appear at
>   the hearing, but you don’t have to. The Court has appointed attorneys
>   (called “Class Counsel”) to represent the Class Members. These
>   attorneys are listed in the Long Form Notice. You may hire your own
>   attorney to appear for you, but if you do so, it will be at your own
>   expense.
>
> WHERE CAN I GET MORE INFORMATION? For more information, visit
>   www.DiceFCRASettlement.com or call 1-855-598-4037.
>
> Please keep this Notice for your records. You may need the Notice ID
>   and Confirmation Code located on the top of this email in the future.
>   Please include your Notice ID on all correspondence with the
>   Settlement Administrator.

I am not sure if this is spam or not.

PS. Posted related question: [Class Action - which options I have?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/class-action-which-options-i-have)

**UPDATE**: Got settlement check $340

Comment: Did you create and/or use an account on dice.com since 2012?

Comment: @WesleyMarshall, I remember I had account there several years ago.

Comment: Did you mean Scam or Spam?

Comment: @Lawrence, both

Comment: Good question, because scam/spam like this exists.

Comment: Worth mentioning here. ***Never*** click links in an email. Even if you know who sent it, don't ***ever*** trust a link. Anyone attempting to verify those links should tread carefully as there is no way to know even whether the displayed URL matches the actual URL shown when you mouse over it. Even then, the email could have some code embedded somewhere that changes it to a different site when you click it (trust me I've seen this done with my own eyes). So please keep that in mind when verifying the links. This may or may not be a legit case, but the email could still be an impersonator.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen/heard of a class action notification scam/spam?

Comment: @Mehrdad: depends on what is meant by 'spam'. Typically, attorneys make reasonable but possibly quite broad attempt to contact potential members of the class (such as for the Optical Disk Drive settlement). They often have no way of knowing if each *potential member* is actually a member (e.g. knowing which of those bought at least one computer with an ODD, in the relevant timeframe). Hence I don't think this could be called spam. Also, the mail volume is almost zero compared to real spam.

Comment: You didn't have to create an account with Dice.  They scrape your data from other sites (LinkedIn, Dribbble, Facebook, StackExchange, etc.) and compile a job/recruiting profile on you that is then sold through their Dice Open Web product to recruiters/headhunters.

Comment: It's legit. Source: I'm the lead plantiff.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's legit... 
[this](https://seekingalpha.com/filing/4335612) is DHI Group's 10-K from 2/7/2019. 
Search for the case#: `331732`

and I'm a member of the class as well ;)

Edited to show my process: 
i received an e-mail from info@dicefcrasettelement.com with the Case Number. 
I googled said case number (Douglas v. DHI Group, Inc. et al.; Case No. 18-cv-331732) 
I then googled the case number which yielded a valid result against "DHI Group" 
then i went o ensure that DHI Group was a valid business by looking for their 10-K, a reporting document for the SEC.

once i ascertained that they were a valid organization and the case was valid, i then submitted my personal information to the website to claim my settlement check.

Comment: Perhaps add something about how this was identified so this answer could be more broadly applied.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Use google.

Comment: So, how can one be sure that www.DiceFCRASettlement.com is not a legit-looking scammer site harvesting personal data?

Comment: @artem How can you be certain that someone doesn't impersonate a lawyer involved in such a settlement to scam you? You honestly cannot without visiting the site, and you cannot visit the site without risks of viruses and malware. Perhaps it's best to not be concerned with the site being a scam and instead just find the contact information for the agency through other means (search engine) and contact them that way with forms they'll likely have on their site. Never click links in an email unless you request it. Even if your bank reports a breach and its legit go to the site to change password.

Comment: The point is, there's no point in visiting the site to confirm if it's legit or not, you have to check **other** sources. If you want to confirm that someone is a lawyer and not an impersonator, you request references from other lawyers or look at court records. If you don't have lawyers that you trust - tough luck.

Comment: @artem If lawyer "Bill Smith" *is* in fact leading the case you can't know for sure whether you are being scammed if someone contacts you under the name "Bill Smith" and claims to be that person.What you can do (which I believe the asker wished to know) is determine whether or not the message of the email is legitimate (i.e. is there even *a* "Bill Smith"?). Short of someone accidentally finding that link we can never know if that's real, but a corroboration of evidence would suggest that the email's *content* is legitimate and should be acted upon. *Never* trust an email, even if you sent it.

Comment: @artem worth mentioning that a common tactic is to change the displayed link to a legit site while the internal hyperlink is actually something insecure. So even if the displayed link copy/pasted into the post is legit we can't ever know for sure if clicking that text actually does takes you to that site (or doesn't silently redirect you through some spyware filled site) without doing digging into the actual source text of the original email. However, this is unlikely to be the case and rampant paranoia probably isn't applicable here.

Answer (score 24):

[This](https://portal.scscourt.org/case/MTkyNzc5Mg==) seems to be the case as listed by Superior Court of California, County of Santa Clara.

I don't see anything there which specifies that particular website as the avenue for filing a claim but all of the other details seem to check out.

edit: to check this, I noted that the email said that there would be a hearing on 2nd August 2019. I went to the court's website and looked at the "Courtrooom Calendars" link. After selecting the correct date and type of case, I found the page for the case which I linked to above